# How to create custom layouts/shapes using canvas element in react/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a 2d interior designing web application, where a user will be able to add images/SVG's to below layout. I am working on canvas element but the problem is canvas element only takes height and width which is why I can create either rectangle or square.
Is it possible using canvas element? If not kindly suggest any other approach. thank you [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Path** for creating custom shapes and call **Clip** function to cut image to the required path

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// creating the path similar to the question
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(4,0);
ctx.lineTo(4,4);
ctx.lineTo(0,4);
ctx.lineTo(0,12);
ctx.lineTo(22,12);
ctx.lineTo(22,0);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.clip(); // cut the canvas to above path

ctx.drawImage(imageTag, 0, 0); // now this will show image to the segmented path
```